SFTP file transfer time stamp

I am writing a python script to check how long the file is staying in the SFTP. Every minute the script will run and it'll check if the file is there or not.
Here's a part of the script checking the file(file's name is "vaishant_test2.log") is in the SFTP or not.

while True:
     file_stat=sftp_client.stat(sftp_directory+'/vaishant_test2.log')
     modification_time=file_stat.st_mtime
     print(modification_time)
     changed_mtime=datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(modification_time)
     formatted_time=changed_mtime.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
     print(formatted_time)
     time.sleep(60)

The file time stamp has remained constant since a day and it's showing a timestamp of "21:47:21".
Is it the 'st_mtime' that's causing the issue or what can I do to check when the file arrived or how can I further develop it to see how long the file stayed in the SFTP.
Any help is appreciated.
I was expecting the program to return a timestamp like,
21:47:21
21:48:21
21:49:21
21:50:21

Edit : My program aims to get a timestamp of the files staying in the SFTP. For every single minute it stays until it gets picked up.
After a few more research I understand that using mtime was not the smartest decision.


I do not understand what does the file modification timestamp have to do with "how long the file stayed in the SFTP".

Why do you expect the mtime to change? Is something supposed to be updating the file every minute?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

My bad @Barmar, Martin and Community. I am actually new to this type of SFTP programs so I just googled a few things and turns out that we do not need the mtime for calculating the time it stayed in the sftp BUT we would require it to calculate it since mtime would be taken as the base value for calculating. Can you please correct me if my way of workflow isn't effective.

I don't understand what you're saying. Why don't you need the mtime? If you subtract the mtime from the current time, that's how long the file has been there. The mtime stays the same, but the difference will increase.

Unless someone overwrites the file. Then the mtime will be updated, and the difference will drop.

Please do not post clarifications in comments. Clarify the question by editing it. And indeed, your explanation does not really clarify things. I still do not understand what are you trying to achieve.

Yes @Barmar indeed I can use it to find the total time it stays but if I have a timestamp for every single minute for every file then it'll be easier to investigate and get file names by simply entering the date & time. Also yes if someone changes the file then mtime will change which can make the calculations wrong.

If you use any commandline/GUI SFTP client to periodically read/refresh the remote directory, does the file timestamp change or not?

Are you trying to get the file's creation time rather than modification time? Unfortunately, most Linux filesystems don't keep this information anywhere. If the information isn't saved, there's nothing you can do in your script to get the information you need.

@MartinPrikryl Hi, no it does not change even after refreshing the SFTP randomly or periodically

@Barmar yes for that problem I have created the system where the script will look for the files landing time and that will be taken as the base time for it and will be considered as the tick tock time. Thanks for the insight.

So why do you expect the file to change when reading it with Paramiko? + I do not understand your last comment? What is "tick tock time"?  Do you just want to calculate file age based on the current time and the file modification time (treating it as file creatiog time, as it does not seem to change on modification)?

Yes @MartinPrikryl it was my mistake to think that mtime changes in the SFTP with every minute. But now I am using mtime to calculate the  tick tock time(time spent on the SFTP). Thanks for your help in clarifying my doubts.

So please either delete your question, or edit it to ask for what you should have asked.
